# Creating a session object

Tags: servlets

When I was learning how to create a session in Servlets. I read that Servlet API provides a class called `HttpSession` to create sessions.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

Then, I was looking at some sample codes and saw this piece of code.

```
// Get the bean from session.

Customer customer = request.getSession(true).getAttribute("userinfo");
```

What exactly is happening here? How did they create a session without using the `HttpSession` class?

Comment: The last line of code does not come from a Servlet? Maybe you should post the entire Method and Class signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
Customer customer = request.getSession(true).getAttribute("userinfo");
```

is equivalent to

```
HttpSession tempVariable = request.getSession(true);
Customer customer = tempVariable.getAttribute("userinfo");
```

but without the temporary variable. It's just method chaining. `request.getSession(true)` is an expression whose type is `HttpSession`, since the `getSession()` method returns a `HttpSession`. So you can call methods of `HttpSession` on this expression.

Note that `request` is an HttpServletRequest, and not an `HttpServlet` as your question says.